# rgl package scatterplot labels

Tags: r, graphics, rgl

I seem to be having problems adding a title and axis labels in the rgl package. Here's a minimum working example:

```
> plot3d(x = c(1,2,3,1), y = c(2,3,1,4), z = c(2,3,4,5), type = 's', size =1)
> decorate3d(main = "My Plot")
```

I see neither labels (which should be set by default in decorate3d) nor `My Plot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decorate3d` adds labels to an existing plot, so in your example

```
plot3d(x = c(1,2,3,1), y = c(2,3,1,4), z = c(2,3,4,5), type = 's', size =1)
```

creates a plot with xlab = 'c(1,2,3,1)', ylab = ' c(2,3,1,4)' etc

`decorate3d` then adds the default values (`x`,`y`, `z`) in addition to the original labels (as it is writing on the current plot).

If you want use `decorate3d` to label the axes, it would be safer to set them as `''` in the original call to `plot3d`

eg

```
plot3d(x = c(1,2,3,1), y = c(2,3,1,4), z = c(2,3,4,5), type = 's', size =1,
       xlab = '', ylab = '', zlab = '')

## then 
decorate3d(main = "My Plot")
## will work as you wish.
```

Comment: Nope, just tried this, I see neither the labels or "My Plot". I've uploaded a jpeg of what I see here: http://temp-share.com/show/KdPf2iy9h

Comment: Hm, weird, I tried it on my mac and it works. It seems that on windows, I need to use an rgl.open() command first. I guess this seems to be an os issue.

Comment: @user1357015 -- strange. I am working on windows XP, R 3.0.0,rgl_0.93.932. (through Rstudio)